# Ladda Button won't work in Safari

Tags: jquery, ladda

Tearing my hair out over this.

Here's my button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ladda-button" data-style="zoom-in">
    <span class="ladda-label">
        Submit
    </span>
</button>
```

using

```
Ladda.bind('.ladda-button', { timeout: 2000 });
```

or

```
Ladda.bind('button[type=submit]');
```

works as advertised in Chrome, but not in Safari.

The only thing I've been able to get to work is this

```
var l = Ladda.create( document.querySelector('.ladda-button'));
$(document).on('click', '.ladda-button', function() {
    l.start();
});
```

which shows the spinner, but the form doesn't submit.

So I tried this

```
var l = Ladda.create( document.querySelector('.ladda-button'));
$(document).on('click', '.ladda-button', function() {
    l.start();
    $(this).submit();
});
```

but it doesn't work; the form will not submit. Not sure what to do at this point, as I've also tried quite a few examples in codepen and from SO and none are working; the spinner refuses to display.

---

### Update

Found a hacky solution, but it's not consistent.

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    var l = Ladda.create(document.querySelector('.ladda-button'));
    l.start();
    alert();
});
```

However, if I remove `alert()` the spinner doesn't show; and the spinner isn't perfectly centered in the button either.

Going bald at this point...

### Update 2

It actually works if I have something that interferes with the normal submit flow.

in my registration page I have a Sweet Alert that fires with a return confirm. Ladda button works perfectly, so it may be that Safari just skips over the firing Ladda in the normal flow?

#### The button

```
<div class="form-group text-center m-t-30">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg ladda-button" type="submit" data-style="zoom-in" id="registration">
        Sign Up
    </button>
</div>
```

#### The javascript

```
$(document).on('click', '#registration', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    swal({
        title: 'Confirm',
        input: 'checkbox',
        inputValue: 0,
        inputPlaceholder: 'Agree',
        confirmButtonText: 'Continue',
        confirmButtonColor: '#5d9cec',
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonColor: '#fffff',
        reverseButtons: true,
        inputValidator: function (result) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                if (result) {
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    reject('Do you agree?');
                }
            })
        }
    }).then(function (result) {
        $('#form-registration').submit();
    });
    $.ladda('stopAll');
});
```

Comment: Does it work on Chrome?

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: @Soolie Yes, it does.

Comment: @mplungjan No, no errors in console.

Comment: @timgavin, Which Safari version are you using? I tested their demo page on http://lab.hakim.se/ladda/ on my safari and it all worked fine. Which means there is definitely something that you are not doing right. Can you check their demo page on Safari and see if it works or not? Just to confirm if it is a browser issue or your code issue?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I'm using the most current version of Safari in High Sierra and the examples work. It's a code issue, but I'm not sure what or where. I've gone through all of my javascript and pretty much stripped out everything and still can't get it to work. I was hoping there was another solution that I could use, as I'm not that proficient in javascript ti figure it out.

Comment: @timgavin, please provide a git repo with minimal example you tried, so one can debug it

Comment: Can you share a live example on codepen/fiddlr etc..?

Comment: @TarunLalwani The code I provided here is the code I'm using. I was starting to think it was my version of Safari but I just tried it on another Mac with Safari and it didn't work there either. Very strange.